# run lerna commands conditionally on module

Tags: javascript, npm, lerna, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I have a monorepo maintained with `lerna` and `npm`.
I'm trying to understand whether I can selectively run `lerna` command depending on where the change has occurred.

For example:
I have the following packages:

```
package-common-base
package-a
package-b
```

In case the change has occurred in `package-common-base` - I'd like to run `lerna run test`
In case the change has occurred in `package-a` or `package-b` (but not in `package-common-base`) - I'd like to run `lerna run test:unit`

I've trying different approaches using the `lerna` flags and also with `@lerna/filter-options` but couldn't find something like that.

Maybe I'm wrong with my conception but I'd really use it, e.g. when I would want to reduce/expand the scope of running tests when a sensitive package is being changed... etc.

Cheers,

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @SKhurana unfortunately no. I saw that many teams and open source packages are using `.sh` scripts to run those checks programatically. I have no example to share since i did not go in that path. Eventually I paralleled the CI tasks to save the build/test times, which is not bad idea anyway

Comment: I found this useful. https://github.com/AnomalyInnovations/serverless-lerna-yarn-starter#deployment-algorithm Please check if that helps you by anychance :)

Comment: yeah.. there's another open-source which I've contributed to in the past, [lerna-project](https://github.com/wix/lerna-script) which can be very useful in those particular customisations

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`--since`](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/core/filter-options#--since-ref) flag to select "time" range of libs that were change in it.

```sh
lerna run test:unit --since master
```

Comment: what i meant was to run different command depending on the module that has been changed

Comment: You can write a script which will use `lerna changed` and run your scripts, based on child_process, or something like this

Comment: yeah I was afraid of this solution... wanted to try and find elegant-built-in capability